# Как в WORDPRESS настроить ссылки

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Например у меня есть такая структура рубрик и записей. Главная рубрика Транспорт от нее наследуются 2 других рубрики - автобусы и легковые автомобили а уже в автобусах и легковых автомобилях находятся записи с наименованиями марок машин. Нужно сделать так: у рубрики транспорт отдельный шаблон в котором есть только список его дочерних рубрик - автобусы, легковые автомобили.  У автобусов и автомобилей тоже отдельный шаблон и там находится список записей названий автомобилей. И само описание автомобиля находиться тоже в отдельном шаблоне. На данный момент у меня есть эта структура и все эти шаблоны. Но я не понимаю как сделать ссылку . Например в шаблоне с автомобилями я вывожу все записи из категории автобусы. получаю список. как сделать так, чтоб нажимая на один из автобусов я переходил на шаблон с описанием именно этого автобуса.   get_permalink меня переводит на главную страницу. а как сделать, чтоб она переводила меня на мой шаблон.  Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Если планируешь на WP сделать подобие drom.ru или auto.ru то с таким подходом у тебя не получится. Слишком много записей в БД получается для таксономий

Comment: вы бы добавили код, которым выводите список с автомобилями